# How to hide a JavaScript pop up after 30 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup, html-helper

I  new on JavaScript. I don't know how to write a JavaScript pop up and how to hide. Pop is showing but it's not hiding. How can it be done?

Here is my code of pop up:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        $('#myModal').delay(0).hide(0); 

    });
</script>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <!--<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>-->
                <h4 class="modal-title">Welcome To HighGainGeneralTrading</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Landing Page Description.</p>
                <form>




                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` + https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/modal/#methods

Answer (score 0):

You can just use setTimeout and set the milliseconds which you wanna hide your element .

You can replace

```
    // setTimeout(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#myModal').hide() }, 3000);
```

with

```
$('#myModal').delay(0).hide(0);
```

Comment: its working but after hide the popup web gone disable i can't press any button or box after hiding the popup

Answer (score 0):

you can use the " setTimeout" method.
see the following link for examples
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
also, you can try chaining " setTimeout" with "toggle" method.